# mergeDuplicates="true" did not work well in MultiSelect mode

Tags: sapui5

I want to achieve mergeDuplicates in Multi Select table, just like [guideline](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/) said:

[image]

But in my [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfjTFadI8luJ45YpMRG6?p=preview), there is still border-top in my checkbox, what should I do? I don't want to overwrite UI5 CSS.

```
<Table
    id="table"
    mode="MultiSelect"
    growingScrollToLoad="true">
    <columns>
        <Column mergeDuplicates="true"><Text text="column1"/></Column>
        <Column><Text text="column2"/></Column>
        <Column><Text text="column3"/></Column>
    </columns>
</Table>
```

Comment: Hope you get some idea after seeing this [Example Plunker link](http://embed.plnkr.co/uFA5S2SMrFDmhtfXBdf7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the concept of `mergeDuplicates` is bound to the cell content and therefore doesn't extend to the selector cell. But obviously, the guideline and the control concept then don't fully match.

I would suggest to slightly modify Ash Kander's proposal. As the table might render individual `ColumnListItem`s individually and at different points in time, attaching to the `onAfterRendering` of the table won't help.

Instead, attach to the `onAfterRendering` of the items by using a delegate. To make this fully work, you have to do this early enough on the template for the items, before data binding starts cloning that template.

In your DEMO, this is easily possible in `onInit` before you create and attach the model (I gave the template the id "cli"):

```
this.byId("cli").addEventDelegate({
  onAfterRendering: function(e) {
    var $dom = e.srcControl.$();
    if ( $dom.has(".sapMListTblCellDup") ) {
      $dom.find("td.sapMListTblSelCol").css("border-topcolor",
          "transparent");
    }
  }
});
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/eNb83KvF1BpAp5eGSpOS?p=preview .

Comment: Thanks ! But why `srcControl` works, but `getSource()` failed ? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.html#event:afterRendering

Comment: In your demo, border will always be set to transparent, I changed your condition to `if($dom.find('td.sapMListTblCellDup').length) ` 
http://plnkr.co/edit/NLaXRZbzqQ08d7VTvnYg?p=preview

Comment: @Tina: Reg. your question about srcControl vs. getSource(): UI5 differentiates between events that are dispatched to controls (usually from the browser, e.g. due to user activity). They are represented by `jQuery.Event` which is close to browser events. Delegates always and only attach to this kind of events (A). The `RenderManager` notifies a control about `afterRendering` with approach (A). 

When controls fire events, they make use of the `sap.ui.base.EventProvider ` which uses `sap.ui.base.Event` that has a `getSource` (B)

`afterRendering`in the View converts from way (A) to (B).

Comment: @Tina: reg. your second remark; you're right, thank's for providing a fixed sample.

Comment: Soo.. Is it the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHqk9.png) that contains the "error" or can we expect a "fix" for this from the framework side? I saw that @Tina already created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1669. I think it should be reopened unless it's clearly the guideline that should fix the image.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in the table renderer. No way you can address it NOW without touching the CSS.

This will work, but this overrides the css (in your controller):

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    $('.sapMListTblSelCol').each(function(index, col) {
        if ($(col).next().hasClass('sapMListTblCellDup')) {
            $(col).css('border-top-color', 'transparent')
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: When `onAfterRendering`,  there is only a table title, no data loaded yet. I've tried `oDataModel.attachRequestCompleted`, even earlier than `onAfterRendering`. `attachRequestCompleted` is later than `onAfterRendering`, but `$('.sapMListTblSelCol').length` still is 1. Any other event suit for this? Thanks very much.

Comment: if the view is binded it should rerender whenever the model changes. can you update your demo to reproduce your issue ?

Comment: As the Table renders each ColumnListItem individually, e.g. when growing is enabled and the user scrolls further down, it is better not to use a jQuery selector to address all rows (ColumnListItems), but to attach the modification code to the onAfterRendering of the ColumnListItem:

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem inside the style.css:

```
td:has(+td.sapMListTblCellDup) {
opacity: 0 !important;
pointer-events: none !important;
}
```